# Adding algorithm parameters in QGIS Graphical Modeller initial dialog box

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Can we have algorithm parameters in the Graphical Modellers initial dialog box. For example, if I use Extract By Location Algorithm, I can set parameters when editing the model but I cannot change them on run time.

[image]

[image]